# Call and start in shell

Tags: shell

If I want to call another batch script from within a batch script I could use

```
CALL File.bat
```

to pause the execution of the current batch file and wait for the CALLed script to complete.

I can use

```
START File.bat
```

if I want them to run simultaneously.

How do I achieve this behavior in a shell script??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wait:

```
#!/bin/bash
# do some stuff
/path/to/other/script
# do other stuff
```

To run it simultaneously (i.e. "in the background"):

```
#!/bin/bash
# do some stuff
/path/to/other/script &
# do other stuff, then optionally:
wait
# this will wait for all background jobs to finish
```

There are other ways, and certain things you should consider about input and output redirection for the background process if you want to provide specific input and/or capture output or errors, but that's the basics.

Answer (score 1):

By “shell“, I assume you mean *NIX sh.

To execute another script and wait for it to complete, do

```
sh file.sh
```

To start it in background, do

```
(sh file.sh) &
```

Comment: ... and in the current path.  As you become more adept in shell programming, you may want to specify the actual brand of the shell (bash or ksh93).

Answer (score 0):

For bash (and other Bourne shell-compatible shells):

- you don't need `CALL`; invoking another script or program executes it synchronously. `someprog.sh`
- you append `&` to a command to run it asynchronously; note that the program will halt if it attempts to read from stdin if it's in the background. `someprog.sh &`